# Getting `NullPointerException` while fetching href tag from DIV with HtmlAgilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Following is my html snippet there is N number of DIV with class name `quality` now i want to extract the `<a href>` of each div which has class name with quality.

Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad

```
<div class="quality wrap">
<a href="/Hotel_Review-g297608-d4464287-Reviews-Eastin_Easy_Citizen_Ahmedabad-Ahmedabad_Gujarat.html" id="property_4464287"class="property_title" onclick=" ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews', 'HotelName', 297608, 0, this.href); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(15176);">
Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad</a> </div>

<div class="quality wrap">
<a href="/Hotel_Review-g297608-d4464287-Reviews-Eastin_Easy_Citizen_Ahmedabad-Ahmedabad_Gujarat.html" id="property_4464287"class="property_title" onclick=" ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews', 'HotelName', 297608, 0, this.href); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(15176);">
Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad</a> </div>

<div class="quality wrap">
<a href="/Hotel_Review-g297608-d4464287-Reviews-Eastin_Easy_Citizen_Ahmedabad-Ahmedabad_Gujarat.html" id="property_4464287"class="property_title" onclick=" ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews', 'HotelName', 297608, 0, this.href); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(15176);">
Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad</a> </div>
```

i have tried with the following

```
var nS = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='quality']//a");
            foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in nS)
            {
                //do something
            }
```

but am getting `NullPointerException` can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **quality wrap** not quality

```
"//div[@class='quality wrap']//a"
```

---

So it would be

```
var hrefList=page.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//div[@class='quality wrap']//a")
                 .Where(e=>e.InnerText.Trim()=="Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad")
                 .Select(x=>x.Attributes["href"].Value)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: can u please tell me how can i get the value of Eastin Easy Citizen Ahmedabad ?